# SWT widgets datetime inserting to mariadb

Tags: java, datetime, swt, prepared-statement, mariadb

I need help. I want to store a datetime value on my database but it says that **the method timestamp is not applicable to the datetime argument**, possibly referring to the preparedstatement code ".setTimestamp". I use the SWT Datetime widget to get the start date but I can't seem to put it into the prepared statement. The datetime values from the SWT widget is passed on the parameter given.

Here's the code below:

```
public void addLeave(String leaveType, DateTime start, DateTime end, int halfDay){
            try{
                Connection con = getConnection();

                String sql = "INSERT into leaves(user_id, leaves_type, leaves_halfDay,leaves_startDate, leaves_endDate) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
                PreparedStatement addLeave = con.prepareStatement(sql);

                addLeave.setString(1, Pkey);
                addLeave.setString(2, leaveType);
                addLeave.setInt(3, halfDay);
                addLeave.setTimestamp(4, start);
                addLeave.setTimestamp(5, end);
                addLeave.execute();

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: `setTimestamp` wants a `java.sql.Timestamp` value not `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.DateTime`. You will have to convert the value.

Comment: ok thanks. I got the idea considering that the swt datetime class does have the getYear, getDay(), etc. methods and maybe you're suggesting I convert it manually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to convert the `DateTime` to `Timestamp` yourself:

```
private Timestamp getTimestamp(DateTime dt)
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,         dt.getYear());
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,        dt.getMonth());
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dt.getDay());
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,  dt.getHours());
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,       dt.getMinutes());
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,       dt.getSeconds());

    return new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
addLeave.setTimestamp(4, getTimestamp(start));
```

Comment: Surely there is a shorter way!

Comment: @RickJames Why would there be? You need to get the time in milliseconds from the DateTime and I don't know a shorter way. Just wrap it in a method.

Comment: If you need the current time, then the _SQL_ `NOW(3)` gives you that.  (OK, maybe you don't want the _current_ time.)

Comment: @RickJames SWT `DateTime` is a clumsy widget. Unfortunately you can't get a `Date` of the epoch time from it directly. Hence the `Calendar` instance. It's a pain, but if the OP wants to get the time stamp from the `DateTime`, then this is the way to do it.

Comment: @Baz Hi, thanks for this and also I believe it should be dt.getMonth()+1 in the case of SWT .

Comment: @Jlorenz1 You're very welcome. Both the `Calendar` and `DateTime` use 0-based months, so a `+1` is not required and even wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Let MySQL do the conversion as you `INSERT`:

```
CREATE TABLE `ts_dt_n` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t2` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `t3` datetime(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

INSERT into ts_dt_n (t2, t3) values (FROM_UNIXTIME(1477155329.123),
                                     FROM_UNIXTIME(1477155329.123));

SELECT t2, t3 FROM  ts_dt_n WHERE id = 5\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
t2: 2016-10-22 09:55:29.123000
t3: 2016-10-22 09:55:29.1
```

If you are coming from Java's millisecond timer, divide by 1000 as you convert and insert:

```
INSERT INTO ts_dt_n (t2, t3) values (FROM_UNIXTIME(1477155829739/1000),
                                     FROM_UNIXTIME(1477155829739/1000));

SELECT t2, t3 FROM  ts_dt_n WHERE id = 6\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
t2: 2016-10-22 10:03:49.739000
t3: 2016-10-22 10:03:49.7
```